# Visual Studio: Typing code vs. drag and drop from the control menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I tried creating a gridview by typing code using another block of code on a different page as an example. I found that, when I ran the program and clicked the Edit button on a row, the fields did not change into textboxes for editing. I did have code to handle the Row Editing event.

In an earlier project I found that I had to double-click the Row Editing event in the Properties window for a gridview to create the event handling code. Typing in that code in the separate aspx.cs file did not work.

I am working with ASP.Net / C#.

What is going on with Visual Studio when I do drag and drop from the control menu as opposed to just typing in code? I am assuming it is adding something that I am missing when I am just typing.

Does anyone else have other examples that didn't work when they typed code that I should watch out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you did a mighty good job copying the HTML, you likely still missed a few properties. That's because the GridView component comes with a bunch of so-called [Design-Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) properties that can (only) be configured from the Properties panel in Visual Studio.

I think you'll find that dragging a control from the toolbox onto your web form will set the control's design-time properties to a specific set of default values. This does not happen when you type the HTML by hand.

Comment: I don't think I've dragged a GridView from the toolbox in my life.  I've written out many dozens of GridViews, and I've always just typed them out.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. That is what I was looking for. I figured there was more going on when I dragged and dropped things.